# Compare to strings and get the distinct in c#

Tags: c#, linq

Example :
 string a= "6,9";
 string b= "5,9";

on comparing the above i need unique elements

result:

a=6;
b=5;

Comment: Don't you mean `a="6"; b="5";`

Comment: Can you explain more? Or give some more examples? Are the numbers always separated by commas? Can there be more than two numbers in each string? Are they always numbers? and so on

Comment: ya they are separated by commas always,their can be more than 2 numbers also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] assets, allassets = null;
int[] list1, list2, removed_list, added_list = null;

assets = a.Split(',');
list1 = Array.ConvertAll(assets, x => int.Parse(x))

allassets = b.Split(',');
list2 = Array.ConvertAll(allassets, x => int.Parse(x));

removed_list = list2.Where(x => !list1.Contains(x)).ToArray(); // which gives =>a
added_list = list1.Where(x => !list2.Contains(x)).ToArray(); // which gives =>b
```

---

I am done with this ,What u people say ?

Answer (score 3):

```
string a= "6,9"; string b= "5,9";
string uniquea = string.Join(",", a.Split(',').Except(b.Split(',')));
string uniqueb = string.Join(",", b.Split(',').Except(a.Split(',')));
```

This will keep duplicates within `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string a= "6,9"; string b= "5,9";
char[] splitters = new[] { ',', ' '};
var aList = a.Split(splitters);
var bList = b.Split(splitters);
var uniqueA = aList.Except(bList).ToList();
var uniqueB = bList.Except(aList).ToList();
```